# socket program setup

Tags: sockets, embedded-linux

I am writing my first socket program to connect to my host to server running on other PC.
I am referring following link but did not got what is the meaning of this line.

http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/12/c-socket-programming/

> The call to the function ‘listen()’ with second argument as ’10′
>   specifies maximum number of client connections that server will queue
>   for this listening socket.

Means to say that it will listen 10 times to new connection request. what actually happen at listen :?:

We will enter while loop once some client connect onto the socket right   And inside while loop does accept blocks if no client is requesting to connect to socket on second loop of while :?:

When we are inside while loop does listen() system call is still working or terminates :?:

Also when we will get out of while loop :?:

Please can someone on forum can help me to understand this.

Comment: Based on the first part you have written, it seem that you want to connect to the other PC.  If that is the case, you need to look at the client code.  The listen is a function for the server side in relation to the number of pending connections allowed. I would also look at the select statement if you are trying to develop a server.

Answer (score 0):

What the `listen` call does is tell the system the size of the queue it should use for new connections. This queue is only used for connections you have not accepted yet, so it's not the number of total connections you will have.

Besides setting the size of the incoming-connections queue, it also sets a flag on the socket that says it's a passive listening socket.

The stuff that `listen` does is set on the socket, so as long as the socket is open the queue and the flag is valid.